# Why should include(CPack) go after the per project package configuration?

Tags: c++, cmake, cpack

I'm experimenting with `CPack` module of `CMake` and got somewhat confusing behavior. I have `CpackMylib.cmake` that is included into a root `CMakeLists.txt`. It looks as follows:

```
include(CPack)             #included on top
install (TARGETS mylib
          LIBRARY
          DESTINATION /usr/lib
          COMPONENT mylib-all
)

install (DIRECTORY include/
          DESTINATION /usr/include/mylib 
          COMPONENT mylib-all)
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "mylib")
set(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB")
```

And when running `make package` it fails to create the package with the following trace:

```
Run CPack packaging tool...
CPack: Create package using STGZ
CPack: Install projects
CPack: - Run preinstall target for: mylib
CPack: - Install project: mylib
CMake Error at /home/krjoff/mylib/cmake_install.cmake:55 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot copy file "/home/krjoff/mylib/libmylib.so" to
  "/usr/lib/mylib.so".


CMake Error at /home/krjoff/mylib/cmake_install.cmake:73 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot set permissions on "/usr/include/mylib"


CPack Error: Error when generating package: mylib
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'package' failed
make: *** [package] Error 1
```

It looks like it simply ignores all variables I put after the `include(CPack)` and trying to build some `STGZ` package and install it immediately. But if I put the `include(CPack)` in the end of the `CpackMylib.cmake` after all configuration's been made it works perfectly fine.

Can someone explain why is it necessary to put the `include(CPack)` after all the configuration settings?

Comment: @YSC Sort of, yes. But this is definitely not a desirable behavior. Moreover it tries to install the default `STGZ` package which I overrode to `DEB`.

Comment: @YSC Sure, as I mentioned including `CPack` after all variables was set worked as expected. I'm just curious about the behavior...

Comment: My bad...............

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how is supposed to work `CPack`. When you `include` it in your `CMakeLists.txt`, it reads all the variables listed in [its documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPack.html) like `CPACK_GENERATOR` or `CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME` and creates the `package`target you then call with `make package`.

If you include it before setting those variables, their value will be ignored.

> Before including this `CPack` module in your `CMakeLists.txt` file, there are a variety of variables that can be set to customize the resulting installers. The most commonly-used variables are:
>
> - `CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME`
>     The name of the package (or application). If not specified, it defaults to the project name.
> - `CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR`
>     The name of the package vendor. (e.g., “Kitware”). The default is “Humanity”.
> - `CPACK_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY`
>     The directory in which CPack is doing its packaging. If it is not set then this will default (internally) to the build dir. This variable may be defined in a CPack config file or from the cpack command line option -B. If set, the command line option overrides the value found in the config file.
> - ...

Source : [CPack --- CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPack.html)

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to ask the following question: Is it a good practice to put all the package related configuration into a separate `.cmake` file containing `include(CPack)` in the end? And then simply included it into a root `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: That's what I do ;)